# Why can't i retrieve text in URL format from a link element?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing an RSS feed that has an element `<link>` with a url within it like so, `<link>http://www.google.com/</link>`; however, when I try to get the url using `node.css('link').text` it returns an empty string.  Is there another attribute I should be accessing?

I'm using nokogiri/ruby.

Example:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.kffl.com/printRSS.php/NFL-ARI'))
    doc.css('item').each do |item|
    puts item.css('link').text
    puts item.css('link').first.text
end
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you provide a code sample that shows it (not) working?

Comment: when inspecting my node I see that the NokoGiri node is there but doesn't seem to have a name attribute... example: `#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x42211be "http://www.kffl.com/gnews.php?id=896864-cardinals-bryan-mccann-re-signed\n            ">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are parsing as HTML, but the source is XML. In [HTML the `link` element is empty](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.3) so Nokogiri parses is as something like `<link></link>http://example.com ...` where the url is a text node outside the `link` element. When you then query the parsed document the `link` elements are empty.

To fix it you should parse as XML:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open('http://www.kffl.com/printRSS.php/NFL-ARI'))
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the text of the "first" item returned by that selector:

```
node.css('link').first.text # => "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: still didn't work. here is the link I'm testing with btw, view-source:http://www.kffl.com/printRSS.php/NFL-ARI

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Nokogiri doesn't recognize links here, but as always in such cases xpath comes to rescue:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.kffl.com/printRSS.php/NFL-ARI'))
doc.css('item').each do |item|
  puts item.xpath("//item['link']/text()").text
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You may to use [.text?](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-text-3F) method to determine that is it a [text node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Text.html). And [next](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-next) method to get a text (to get next element).

```rb
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.kffl.com/printRSS.php/NFL-ARI'))

doc.css('item')[0].css('link').first.text?
# => false

doc.css('item')[0].css('link').first.next.text?
# => true

doc.css('item')[0].css('link').first.next.text

# => "http://www.kffl.com/gnews.php?id=901900-cardinals-tyrann-mathieu-expected-to-start-camp-on-pup\n            "
```

*I don't know why*